# Use https with HCL Connections Component Pack 6.5 from IHS to K8S

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-connections, ibmhttpserver, hcl-component-pack

The [Component Pack documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_config_om_http_server.html) uses http for the connection from IHS to the Kubernetes backend. This is not up-to-date any more, so I'd like to use https for those backend connection as well as in IHS like this:

```
User <----- https -----> IHS <----- https -----> K8S Backend
```

Following HCLs documentation, we just got

```
User <----- https -----> IHS <----- http -----> K8S Backend
```

[Component Packs ingress](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/cp_installing_ingress_controller.html) doesn't have any configuration options for https documented.

Answer (score 1):

I unpacked the chart and looked at it's default `values.yml`. It seems that IBM/HCL doesn't follow the Helm template, which allow configuring https in almost any charts using `ingress.tls`.

The only possible way seems to be manually modifying our ingress ressources like this:

1. `kubectl edit ing cnx-ingress-orient-me`
2. Replace `*` by a subdomain (e.g. `ing`): `- host: ing.k8s.internal`
3. Add a `tls` section in `spec`:

```
 tls:
  - hosts:
    - ing.k8s.internal
```

4. Save the changes and verify your ingress is avaliable using https, for example with the comp

   `curl "https://ing.k8s.internal/social/views/login.html" --head` should return `HTTP/2 200`

We need to repat this for **all** deployed ingress ressources. When all features are deployed, there are 4:

```
$ kging | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'
cnx-ingress-appreg
cnx-ingress-orient-me
cnx-ingress-sanity
external-service
```

#### Automation

Its also possible to automate those changes by exporting the ingress to a file:

```
kubectl get ing cnx-ingress-orient-me -o yaml > /tmp/ing.yml
```

No we can search/replace using `sed`

```
# Replaces the general HTTP listen hostname
sed -i "s/host: '\*\./ing./g" /tmp/ing.yml
# Adds tls-tree with corresponding indention
sed "s/\(\s*\)\(rules:\)/tls:\n\1- hosts:\n\1\1- ing.k8s.internal\n\1\2/g" /tmp/ing.yml
```

To apply our changes:

```
kubectl replace -f /tmp/ing.yml
```